# How to Convert Date, Time and UTC Offset to Local DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timezone

I need to get a local timezone datetime from the following XML elements:

```
<TransactionDate>20191202</TransactionDate>
<TransactionTime>234026</TransactionTime>
<TransactionTimezone>UTC-06:00:00</TransactionTimezone>
```

My local UTC offset is -05:00:00. After getting TransactionDate and TransactionTime into td and tt Date variables, I can build a Datetime like this:

```
Dim ldDate As New Date(td.Year, td.Month, td.Day, tt.Hour, tt.Minute, tt.Second)
```

I could parse out the '-06' from TransactionTimeZone and determine that I need to add 1 hour to ldDate, but there must be a more elegant way.  Any ideas?

Comment: ldDate.AddHours(x) where x is the difference in hours

Comment: I'd like to accept Jimi's comment as the answer.  I'll post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small procedure that returns a DateTime in the local TimeZone from a DateTime in an originating TimeZone:

```
Public Function P_ConvertToLocalDatetime(ByVal aOriginDateTime As Date, 
                                         ByVal aOriginTimeZone As String, 
                                         ByRef aLocalDateTime As Date) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim liHour As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(aOriginTimeZone, 4, 3))
        Dim liMinute As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(aOriginTimeZone, 8, 2))
        Dim liSecond As Integer = CInt(Strings.Right(aOriginTimeZone, 2))
        With aOriginDateTime
            Dim offset As New DateTimeOffset(.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second, New TimeSpan(liHour, liMinute, liSecond))
            aLocalDateTime = offset.LocalDateTime
        End With
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I'm calling it with this:

```
Dim lLocalDateTime as Date        
If Not P_ConvertToLocalDatetime(aTransactionDatetime, 
                                aTransactionTimezone, 
                                aLocalDateTime) Then
    Throw New Exception("Unable to convert TransactionDatetime to local time")
End If
```

... where `aTransactionTimezone` is of type String with a value like `"UTC-6:00:00"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have transactions **from all the world** this might help you to use as a base and working on to improve.

```
Private Function FromWorldTimeToMyLocalTime(noSpacesDateTimeTransaction As String, transactionZoneString As String) As Date
    Dim transactionDtTime As Date = Date.ParseExact(noSpacesDateTimeTransaction, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Return DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(transactionZoneString).BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours, transactionDtTime)
End Function
```

Usage (Here the example shows a transaction is done by Hawai):

```
 ‘Here is your complete string as you have in your xml tags (date + time) it’s presumed the transaction is come by  Hawai 
 Dim myDateTimeFromTransactionTime As String = FromWorldTimeToMyLocalTime("20191202234026", "Hawaiian Standard Time").ToString
 Console.WriteLine("MyTime from transaction is " & myDateTimeFromTransactionTime)
```

To get all timezone infos you can use this to have an idea.

```
Dim timeZones As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo) = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
For Each timeZoneInfo As TimeZoneInfo In timeZones
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(timeZoneInfo.Id) & "  " & CStr(timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours))
Next
```

Comment: Careful.  The example time zone string in the OP is not the type that would be found by `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`.  But also, one should never simply add the `BaseUtcOffset` of a `TimeZoneInfo` object.  Doing so ignores any transitions that are present, such as for start or end of DST or for change in standard time.

Comment: All you have writing is right, but, as I wrote in my answer “use as a base and working on to improve” is base to have the idea from where start with.